# AWS Lightsail LAMP PHP7 mod-rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, php7

I just installed a fresh AWS Lightsail LAMP stack with php7.4 and a lets encrypt ssl
Docs say Mod-rewrite is installed/enabled by default however I get a 404 when I go to any url on my site that is domain.com/contact but of course domain.com/contact.php works

I looked at my bitnami-ssl.conf file and see a line that has a Allow Override All which I believe should make the mod_rewrite work?
[image]

I am not sure what else I need? Suggestions how to troubleshoot? thank you

Comment: Why should `/contact` "work" if the actual URL should be `/contact.php`? Simply having mod_rewrite installed doesn't magically allow extensionless URLs to work - if that is what you are thinking?

Comment: MrWhite please see my updated screenshot in my original post. I believe lightsail does not support .htaccess files so I have my mod rewrite rules ion the bitnami conf file which should . also stopped and restarted the server however am still missing something I guess